# Book/article recommendations for an introduction to hypergroups and subsequent research

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, book-recommendation, topological-groups

I'm a grad student and I'm choosing an area to follow on my doctorate (in?) and I've been thinking about extension of topological group theory results to topological hypergroups, but for that I need to be introduced to the subject.

What is an awesome book which could serve as an introduction to the theory of hypergroups in general? As corollaries: is there such a book? Is the subject too new?

Bonus question: What are the directions this area is following/heading towards? Specific examples as papers would be more than welcome.

Comment: If you're thinking about anything for your PhD, you *should* also be thinking of a lecturer to work with in that field, so wouldn't it be wiser to ask her/him this question? BTW, I've no pale idea what hypergroups can be...and I worked quite a bit with groups in graduate school, go figure.

Comment: I understand, I was just trying to get to him with some experience. Btw, Hypergroups are a pair (G, x) where the operation x is multivalued, e.g.  ab = x, y, z. We then say that ab = {x,y,z}

Comment: Thanks @Henrique. I shall read about that later.

Answer (score 2):

See references in http://planetmath.org/hypergroup

Besides see
B.Davvaz, W.Dudek, T.Vougiouklis, A generalization of $n$-ary algebraic systems.
*Communications in Algebra*, v.37(2009), pp.1248–1263,

and other papers of W.Dudek.

Answer (score 1):

This paper seems to have the most citations among those I saw:
Hypergroups and hypergroup algebras:http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01088201

But this book has even more (and some of it is on Google books):
Generalized wavelets and hypergroups:[http://www.amazon.com/Generalized-Wavelets-Hypergroups-Khalifa-Trimeche/dp/9056990802](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9056990802)

I would recommend trying them out before buying (check out previews!) The level may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to realize is that the term "hypergroup" is used for several different mathematical objects. Besides the generalisation of a group that you mention which allows the multiplication to be multivalued, there is also the notion of a hypergroup that are topological spaces with a convolution product for measures on this space which satisfies several axioms which are automatically satisfied for the convolution on a locally compact topological group. This direction comes from harmonic analysis, the reference given by Rushton concern this notion of hypergroup. See also the book by Bloom and Heyer http://books.google.fr/books?id=EUVGq4ciuMsC&dq=bloom+heyer&source=gbs_navlinks_s.

For hypergroups in your sense (hyperstructures) see also the Wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergroup and its references.

Comment: go through this paper